# how to synchronize two threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to create two threads (T1 and T2) so that, when T1 do some processing T2 should be paused, and when T1 finishes T2 should start.
what is the recommended way to implement such behaviour

Comment: why u not use asynctask . i mean in post  execute you can call other asynctask fot t2

Comment: Why use 2 Threads then in the first place? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: "what is the recommended way to implement such behaviour" Not using two threads. You are describing the behaviour of one thread.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement _coroutines_ in Java?  (Google it!)